# Error: [Previous line repeated 1 more time] TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python

I did an extended Euclidean algorithm:

```
def extended_euclid(a,b):
    if a==0: 
        return (b, 0, 1) 
    else:
        div, x, y = extended_euclid(b % a, a)
        if div != 1:
            print(div)
        else:
            return (div, y - (b // a) * x, x)
a=int(input('a: '))
b=int(input('b: '))

print(extended_euclid(a, b))
```

and I get errors for some numbers. 525 and 231 for example give an error:

```
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

For some other numbers it works:

```
>>>a: 60623
>>>b: 423432
<<<(1, 55151, -7896)
```

Maybe someone knows how to fix the error?

Comment: Your branch with `print(div)` does not return anything.

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything is works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at what happens when the remainder (div) is not equal to 1

```
def extended_euclid(a,b):
    if a==0: 
        return (b, 0, 1) 
    else:
        div, x, y = extended_euclid(b % a, a)
        # When the following if statement is true, extended_euclid() returns nothing
        if div != 1:
            print(div)
        else:
```

The error comes from the last statement `print(extended_euclid(a, b))` when you attempt to print a value that was never returned from `extended_euclid()`.